# Borderless Window monogame

Tags: xna, monogame, borderless

I'm trying to port a XNA game to MonoGame. I only want to target Windows platform.
I want to display the game in a borderless window. I do that, this way, in my XNA game:

```
private void SetForm()
    {
        Form myForm = (Form)Form.FromHandle(this.Window.Handle);
        myForm.Name = "WIPForm";            
        int width = 1024;
        int height = 768;           
        IntPtr auxptr = (this.Window.Handle);
        SafeNativeMethods.MoveWindow(
            (int)auxptr,
            0,
            0,
            Properties.Settings.Default.width,
            Properties.Settings.Default.height,
            1);
        myForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        myForm.SetBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    }
```

When I test this code in the monogame version myForm = null.
Is there any way to draw a borderless window in the monogame version?

Comment: So Monogame doesn't give you the handle of your game window? Maybe there is some Monogame-specific way to get window handles, because the code seems ok.

Comment: Try using `Mouse.WindowHandle`.

Answer (score 10):

In the constructor of your MonoGame game class:

set:

```
Window.IsBorderless = true;
```

As per:
https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/432292